# Modify function to only return values for the user that’s logged in

Tags: functions, users

I'm trying to modify a function in a plugin so that it only returns the custom post type (venues) of the user that’s logged in (by default it displays all venues). This is my first time customizing a function, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I've put into my functions.php file:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

if ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID) {
    add_action('tribe_events_community_form', 'community_events_venue_select_menu_current_user');
function community_events_venue_select_menu_current_user( $event_id = null ) {
 if ( !$event_id ) {
     global $post;
     if( isset( $post->post_type ) && $post->post_type == 'tribe_events' ) {
         $event_id = $post->ID;
     } elseif( isset( $post->post_type ) && $post->post_type == 'tribe_venue' ) {
         return;
     }
 }
 do_action( 'tribe_venue_table_top', $event_id );
}
}
```

I'm getting the following two errors for the function, even though there are thousands of the 'tribe_events' and 'tribe_venue' post types in my database:

> Notice: Undefined variable: post
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

on this line:
`if ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID) {`

---

Additionally, when I changed the name of the default function (in the plugin) to my custom function name, its returning this error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function community_events_venue_select_menu_current_user()`

Comment: Has the custom post type being referenced been created yet?

Comment: @dMcClintock First, thanks for your help! Yes, there are actually thousands of this custom post type in my database. I tried changing `TribeEvents::POSTTYPE` (thinking that might throw an error since it was code from within the plugin) to `tribe_events`, which is the exact value of the post_type in my posts table, but that still returns the same two errors.

Comment: Refer to my modified answer. Was the plugin working before (sans the desired functionality, of course), prior to adding the author-dependent conditional?

Comment: Plugins are loaded before the functions.php file is included, so when the plugin tries to call your function, it does not exist in memory yet. Also you must call global $post; before you can use it in your function.

Comment: You are calling `$post` too late. Define it when you set `$current_user`

Comment: @PieterGoosen is right, I neglected to include `$post` after `global`. Your first attempt should work by adding that. Modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

See below for my version of what you are trying to do. However keep in mind that adding this function to your functions.php, and changing the plugin to point to this function, will produce an error that the function does not exist. This is because plugins are included before functions.php, so when the plugin loads your function doesn't exist yet. You will need to make this change inside the plugin itself.

Modifying plugins is generally not a great idea because as the plugin updates it will overwrite your changes. If you think that it is still a good idea in your case, I would suggest changing the name of the plugin, or setting the version number very high to prevent updates from breaking your code. Of course from then on it will be up to you to manually update/maintain the custom version of the plugin as needed.

```
function community_events_venue_select_menu_current_user( $event_id = null ) {

    global $current_user, $post;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    if ( $post->post_author != $current_user->ID ) {
        return; // Do nothing if this post author does not match our current user id
    }

    if ( ! $event_id ) {
        if ( isset( $post->post_type ) && $post->post_type == 'tribe_events' ) {
            $event_id = $post->ID;
        } elseif ( isset( $post->post_type ) && $post->post_type == 'tribe_venue' ) {
            return;
        }
    }
    do_action( 'tribe_venue_table_top', $event_id );
}
add_action( 'tribe_events_community_form', 'community_events_venue_select_menu_current_user' );
```

Comment: Thank you @MattKeys that makes sense now why it was throwing those errors. I tried adding your function to the plugin but I'm getting the following error: `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_author`

Comment: Change the first if statement's comparison operator back to `==`. Then move your entire second if statement (including the `do_action` line) into the first, replacing the line that currently says `return;`. You can also eliminate `global $post;` as you've already made that call at the beginning of the function.

Comment: dMcClintock is right about the second call to global $post; I missed that.

However the rest seems to be just a difference in style, both should work the same. Does the notice you are getting say what line number the error is on? And is that line number inside of this function, or elsewhere?

Comment: Thank you both. In each case, I'm getting `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_author` on this line: `if ( $post->post_author != $current_user->ID ) {` which is inside of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_currentuserinfo();` to pull the current user's ID, then check it against `$post->post_author` with an if statement.

```
global $post, $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

if ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID) {
    // Do something
}
```

There should be an `add_action` either directly before or after the function; place that line inside the if statement so the function is only registered if the author condition is true.

For your case, use the following:

```
add_action('tribe_events_community_form', 'community_events_venue_select_menu_current_user');
function community_events_venue_select_menu_current_user( $event_id = null ) {
    global $post, $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    if ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID) {
        if ( !$event_id ) {
            if( isset( $post->post_type ) && $post->post_type == 'tribe_events' ) {
                $event_id = $post->ID;
            } elseif( isset( $post->post_type ) && $post->post_type == 'tribe_venue' ) {
                return;
            }
        }
        do_action( 'tribe_venue_table_top', $event_id );
    }
}
```